# How to create a virtual table with a date sequence relating with another table?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables.

One table has the employee point and the other has the employee's data.

You can see both tables below:

Table: Horas_trabalho

```
315           |          09:45:00           |          2015-08-15
315           |          05:55:00           |          2015-08-17
315           |          05:55:00           |          2015-08-15
315           |          10:50:00           |          2015-08-13
315           |          05:55:00           |          2015-08-14
315           |          05:55:00           |          2015-08-13
315           |          09:44:00           |          2015-08-13
315           |          05:55:00           |          2015-08-01
315           |          09:47:00           |          2015-08-04
315           |          09:47:00           |          2015-08-04
315           |          14:27:00           |          2015-08-01
315           |          15:50:00           |          2015-08-04
```

Table: funcionario

```
315           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          NULL           |          5793           |          10829720267           |          2000-08-19           |          NULL           |          9           |          2
```

With the query, below...

```
SELECT f.matricula, f.nome, h.data, h.hora from funcionario f
LEFT JOIN horas_trabalho h ON h.funcionario_id = f.id
WHERE f.id = 315
ORDER BY h.data;
```

I have this result:

```
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-01           |          05:55:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-01           |          09:44:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-01           |          14:27:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-01           |          10:49:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-04           |          15:50:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-04           |          10:53:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-04           |          09:47:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-04           |          09:47:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-04           |          05:55:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-05           |          05:55:00
```

And I want to get the points that the employee doesn't have in the days too (that doesn't exists in the database). Something, like this:

```
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-03           |          NULL
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-04           |          15:50:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-04           |          10:53:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-04           |          09:47:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-04           |          09:47:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-04           |          05:55:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-05           |          05:55:00
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-06           |          NULL
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-07           |          NULL
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-08           |          NULL
5793           |          "EISZUPERIO DA SILVA ROCHA"           |          2015-08-09           |          NULL
```

**Detail: When the time value is NULL, the date is null too. But I want to show when the employee doesn't have a record in this date. I still couldn't think in how to do that.**

Answer (score 0):

You could create a date sequence using a tally table, which is a table with a single row of dates in it.  Here is the basic syntax for creating this table with 10000 days, counting up from 1/1/1990-

```
select dateadd(dd,(row_number() over (order by (select null))),'1/1/1990') n
from (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
cross join (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
cross join (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
cross join (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n)
```

From here you would just need to left join from the tally table to your main query on the dates generated by the tally table.  This will create a row for each date, regardless of if there is data in Table: Horas_trabalho (blank rows in Table: Horas_trabalho will show up as NULL).

```
select *
from
(
    select dateadd(dd,(row_number() over (order by (select null))),'1/1/1990') n
    from (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    cross join (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    cross join (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
    cross join (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n)
)
left join 
(
    SELECT f.matricula, f.nome, h.data, h.hora 
    from funcionario f
    LEFT JOIN horas_trabalho h ON h.funcionario_id = f.id
    WHERE f.id = 315
    ORDER BY h.data
) d
on t.n = d.hora
```

Comment: If you have more ideas, please, let me know. And thanks for the help!